# Designing REST api for function calls

Tags: java, spring, rest

So I am building a REST APi that will be responsible for running various jobs on a special hardware.

So I understand that REST is used for accessing resources and not calling functions.
So what are the recommendations and best way to design an API for responsible for calling functions.

For example I will have an api `job/run` which will return the PID of job if job was sucesfully ran.
I'll also have a `job/{pid}` for accessing information about a given job. and `job/cancel/{pid}` for stopping said job.

Comment: OK so what is the question?

Comment: this guy has designed an api to access spring-batch and quartz tasks execution metas: https://github.com/chrisgleissner/spring-batch-rest it could work as an example on what you're trying to do

Comment: You can use the REST API for calling functions. your problem is not clear, what have you tried and didn't work

Comment: The "RESTful" way would be something like: a) create a job and return PID: `POST /jobs`, b) retrieve information about  a job: `GET jobs/{pid}`, c) cancelling a job: `DELETE jobs/{pid}`.

Answer (score 1):

> So what are the recommendations and best way to design an API for
>   responsible for calling functions

1. Create a user: POST /users
2. Delete a user: DELETE /users/1
3. Get all users: GET /users
4. Get one user: GET /users/1

> To GET Record

**Bad designs**

```
GET /FetchUsers                  // To fetch all records
GET /getAllUsers/12              // To fetch specific records
```

**Preferred Designs**

```
GET /users                      //To fetch all records
GET /users/12                   // To fetch specific records
```

> To Crete Record

**Bad designs**

```
POST /createUsers                //To create users
GET  /createrecordforUsers      //To fetch all records
```

**Preferred designs**

```
POST /users                     //To create users records
```

> To Update Record

**Bad designs**

```
PUT  /updateUsersid               // To update user
POST /id/modifyuser              // To update users
```

**Preferred designs**

```
PUT /users/:id                     // To update users
```

> To Delete Record

**Bad designs**

```
DELETE /deleteuser/id              //To delete users
POST   /id/removeusers            //To delete users
```

**Preferred designs**

```
DELETE /users/:id               // To delete users
```

Comment: Perfect. Very concise and straight to the point. Do you have any other sources / tips you could point me to.

Answer (score 1):

Below points should be considered

1. Platform independence . (Any client should be able to call the API, regardless of how the API is implemented internally)
2. Service evolution .(The web API should be able to evolve and add functionality independently from client applications.)

A resource has an identifier, which is a URI that uniquely identifies that resource. For example, the URI for a particular customer order might be:

Request : GET -> https://domain/orders/1
Response :
JSON
{"orderId":1111,"amount":99.90,"productId":1,"quantity":1}

The most common operations are GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE.

- GET retrieves a representation of the resource at the specified URI. The body of the response message contains the details of the requested resource.
- POST creates a new resource at the specified URI. The body of the request message provides the details of the new resource. Note that POST can also be used to trigger operations that don't actually create resources.
- PUT either creates or replaces the resource at the specified URI. The body of the request message specifies the resource to be created or updated.
- PATCH performs a partial update of a resource. The request body specifies the set of changes to apply to the resource.
- DELETE removes the resource at the specified URI.

REST APIs use a stateless request model. HTTP requests should be independent and may occur in any order, so keeping transient state information between requests is not feasible.

We can return response with hypermedia links as spring boot having this feature

[Spring Boot:] https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/

https://domain/orders (Better)

https://domain/create-order (Avoid)

- A resource doesn't have to be based on a single physical data item. For example, an order resource might be implemented internally as several tables in a relational database, but presented to the client as a single entity. Avoid creating APIs that simply mirror the internal structure of a database.
- A client should not be exposed to the internal implementation.
- Avoid requiring resource URIs more complex than (order/collection/item/details)

**Summary**

```
- Pagination Support  : /orders?limit=25&offset=50
- Error handing : 
- API Version (avoid as much as if possible)
```

Refer here https://www.openapis.org/blog/2017/03/01/openapi-spec-3-implementers-draft-released